# Selenium C# - How to Remove or Replace target=_blank from an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, dom, selenium-webdriver

I have the following html code snippet:

```
<p>
  <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" onclick="s_objectID="https://www.google.com/_1";return
    <span class>"ms-rteStyle-external-link-small">
       "Production Efficiency Status"
       ::after
    </span>
   </a>
</p>
```

When the link is clicked it opens on a new tab. I would like to remove target="_blank" or replace it with target="_self" so that the link opens on the same tab.

Using Selenium (ChromeDriver), C# and JavaScript, I have done the following:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor jsX = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver.driver;

var elm = Driver.driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#WebPartWPQ5 > div.ms-rtestate-field > div > div > p:nth-child(3) > a > span"));

// jsX.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute(\"target\", \"_self\")", elm);
jsX.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute(\"target\")", elm);

elm.Click();
```

The above code still opens the link on a new tab. Please point me to the correction I need to do so that clicked link is opened on the same tab.

I have used the following references:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute
3. [Selenium - Universal Way to Convert "WebElement" to Javascript or JQuery Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962307/selenium-universal-way-to-convert-webelement-to-javascript-or-jquery-object)

Comment: Can you share why would you like to remove `target="_blank"`? What is your _Manual Step_ which you are trying to _Automate_?

Comment: Hi there, here are the overall manual steps I was trying to do: 1. Find a link element on a page, 2. Remove the target attribute of the link element, 3. Click on the link element, it opens on the same tab.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will remove the "target" attribute from `<a>` tags:

```
driver.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByTagName('a').removeAttribute('target')");
```